# What happens in an 8085 if HOLD, READY, and RESET requests are received at the same time?

Tags: microprocessor, 8085

What happens if an 8085 microprocessor 8085 is executing a program and it gets a request from the Ready, Hold and Reset pins at the same time?

How will microprocessor respond?

Comment: Please **edit your title**.  We can hear you just fine, you don't have to shout.  If you have a typical English keyboard, the caps lock key is just to the left of the 'A'.  Please disengage it and try again.

Comment: I'd guess that Reset would take precedence, but why don't you read the manual?

Comment: Reset has to be the highest priority signal (logically).

Comment: Hold on while I go back to the 1980s and check.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

The RESET, HOLD and READY signals are sampled at different times in the T-states, which is explained in the appropriate manual.

Why are you using an almost 40-year-old microcontroller might be a good question.